# Why some key-value data stores reject the concept of tables/buckets?

Tags: database, key-value-store

Some key-value datastores (e.g. C version of Berkeley DB, Foundation DB, sqlite 4 core) use flat key-value space, that is they don't have the notion of buckets and, as far as I can see, the only way of supporting grouping data is having part of your keys associated with a corresponding table/bucket or, if scans are not needed, at least have some type tag embedded in the value.

Embedding type information, e.g. prefixing keys with bucket name seem to lead to inevitable increase of datastore size for no obvious benefit for the user of such datastore.
And on the other hand separating datastores, e.g. using one bucket - one datastore scheme may not work well with transactions that touch multiple buckets.

Given this, I wonder what is the benefit of rejecting buckets and why datastore engine's authors may consider doing this? Perhaps there are other benefits other than simplicity of the datastore and ability to fetch contents of the entire datastore in a series of easier-to-code scan operations.

Answer (score 0):

At least recent versions of BerkeleyDB support multiple buckets that is you can create multiple "databases" inside the same environment, and transactions spans all databases created against the same env.

In the case of sqlite 4 or sqlite 3 lsm extensions, it is probably to keep things simple.

Actually, the only okvs that has multiple tables is wiredtiger. As far as I know it is an optimization.

Mind the fact that FoundationDB has the concept of `Subspace` and `Directory`.

Comment: I think you're talking about Berkeley DB in Java, not C version of BDB (as I indicated in my post). If I'm not missing something it still doesn't have the concept of buckets - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/api_reference/C/frame_main.html

Comment: I am reading this "a Berkeley DB database could be thought of as a single table within a larger database." for me table == bucket. What did I miss.

Comment: True, but as far as I can see one can't have transaction spanning across more than one DB. It would have to be an application-level 2PC protocol or the like to achieve ACID if multiple DBs are used.

Comment: `DB_TXN` methods are attached to `DB_ENV` hence AFAIU it works across `DB` ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/api_reference/C/frame_main.html

Comment: I didn't know that, for some reason I thought that different DBs won't be able to share the same transaction. My knowledge might be outdated though. Great point, thanks for sharing.